# Determine the area bounded by the curve and x-axis

Tags: integration, derivatives

$y = 20x-2x^2$

How to determine the area bounded by the curve and x-axis using derivates?

Comment: Usually you use antiderivatives rather than derivatives to calculate areas.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

You mean using integrals. This curve has two $x$ intercepts, at $x=0$ and $x=10$. Thus we wish to evaluate

$$\int_0^{10}20x-2x^2\,\mathrm dx=10x^2-\frac{2}{3}x^3$$

evaluated between $0$ and $10$, or $\frac{1000}{3}$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{equation}
y= 20 x - 2 x^2 = 2x(10-x)
\end{equation}
the intersection points of $x$ and $y$ lines are (0,0) and (10,0). Then, the integral of the $y$ between these two points give the area.
\begin{align}
\int_0^{10} 20 x -2x^2 dx & = 10 x^2 - \frac{2}{3} x^3 \Big|_0^{10}
\notag \\
& = 1000 - \frac{2}{3}1000
\notag \\
& = \frac{1000}{3}
\end{align}